# Overriding method from Object class in Java

Tags: java, overriding

When I want to override method **equals** from class Object in some subclass A, why type of parameter of overridden function in subclass A has to be Object and not A. Like this

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
...
}
```

and not this:

```
public boolean equals(A o) {
...
}
```

Comment: Because 1) this lets you introduce equality conditions of two objects of different types 2) it is the base method of the `Object` initially so that it would be odd if `Object` would try to test for equality to something that is not an Object since everything is an `Object`

Comment: Because it is coming from `Object.equals`, you are overriding this one and it does not support generic types.

Comment: Just a hint of more work: if you override equals(), you should override hashCode().

Answer (score 3):

`equals` is declared in the parent class, Object. When you try to change the type of the parameter, you are necessarily making it more restrictive (since Object is the least specific type there can be).

Suppose you try to do this

```
Object obj = new A();
obj.equals("str"); // should return false
```

On the second line, the compiler doesn't know anything about `A`. There could be anything in that variable. As far as the compiler knows, this is just another Object. It doesn't care that the method has been overriden in A. `Object.equals` takes Object as a parameter, so this is perfectly valid.

If your `A` implementation had been overriden with a more restrictive type, you would have a fundamental incompatibility. The method cannot handle a String, yet it is perfectly possible to pass one.

Comment: Is mine explanation valid? 

Object obj = new A();

obj's :
1) Declared type - type Object
2) Real type - type A

When we want to assign variable a to variable b, their declared types must be the same.
If parameter of overridden function is : A a - declared type of a (which is A) and declared type of obj (which is Object) are not compatible and we cannot assign here.

But when parameter is: Object a - declared type of a and obj are now the same, and now we can assign obj to a

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are **overriding** and not **overloading**. When you **override** any method, the method signature should be same.

Check the following from lines from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

> The overriding method has the same name, number and type of
> parameters, and return type as the method that it overrides. An
> overriding method can also return a subtype of the type returned by
> the overridden method. This subtype is called a covariant return type.

You may also find [this tutorial](https://www.codejava.net/java-core/the-java-language/12-rules-of-overriding-in-java-you-should-know) useful.

Comment: It is not required to be the *same*. It must be equally, or less restrictive. In most cases this means it will be the same, but not always.

Comment: @Michael - I agree with you. I hope the OP will find your clarification useful.

Comment: So basically declared type of argument and method's parameter must be the same?

Comment: @pino123 - That's right. Make sure to check the links mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @pino123 - I hope the solution worked for you. Do not forget to mark the answer as accepted so that future visitors can also use the solution confidently.

Answer (score 0):

In order to override a method in a subclass, the method needs to have the same name, same parameters or signature, and same return type (or sub-type).

Comment: Thats good and easy explanation. Thanks. You can read my reply to comment from Michael and tell me is my explanation Valid? Both of yours and Michael's response is great